# How to handle mobile version on github

Tags: git, version-control, github, dvcs

So I want to develop a mobile version of a software I created recently and which is hosted on github. This version should be a own project and isn't supposed to be merged with the original one. I don't have major experience with version controlling software and this I am a bit confused how to proceed with this.

Should I create a new branch for it, fork my own repo (as shown [here](http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github)) or are there other possibilities?

Comment: It almost certainly shouldn't be a branch. I assume you'll be sharing code between the two projects?

Comment: No, I want do use the code of the first on as a base for the second, but no sharing after that.

Comment: The projects will be maintained completely separately after the initial split?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know the right approach without knowing more about the projects themselves.

If the projects are intended to be maintained entirely apart from one another after the initial split, as you suggest in your comments, you can simply clone the original project (call it `project-a`), change your remote to point to a new repository on GitHub (call it `project-b`), and push to that. (This is what your linked article suggests.)

For example:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/project-a.git project-b
cd project-b
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/project-b.git
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:user/project-b.git
git push -u origin master
```

Note that the `project-b` repository will need to be created in the GitHub web UI before you can `push`.

However, if the projects are closely related it might make sense to use [Submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule.html) (or something similar; there are a number of alternatives) to make one a subproject of the other, or to make a common set of libraries a subproject of both of them.